# Quadratic Form And The First Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the connection between the quadratic form of a plane/surface and the first fundamental form?

P.S I am more acquainted with the technical way of founding the quadratic form and the fundamental form and less with the theory

Comment: How is the quadratic form  of a surface defined?

Comment: it is $x^t S x$

Comment: So are you referring to a quadric surface defined by a (quadratic equation) $x^\top Sx = c$? Your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The first fundamental form (i.e. the metric tensor) of a surface  *is* a quadratic form associated to the surface. So is the second fundamental form. Do you have more details/context you could add?